# Heroku Redis logs are noisy - how can they be filtered out?

Tags: logging, heroku, redis

The Heroku Redis logs are so noisy. Is there a way to filter them out?

Comment: I can't see any useful logs anymore because of all the pollution Heroku Redis makes.

Comment: Same problem here, still

Answer (score 3):

There are a few options. You can select which dyno you want :

```
heroku logs --source app --dyno web
```

Or you can use one of the heroku log addons, which provide more advanced filtering and retention.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same situation and solve it using the answer by @Christian Rondeau, thanks a lot man!

But I would like to add some details for the for newbies (like me).

First of all I strongly recommend to get acquainted with the [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging) (it's quite short)

All the dynos in you application you can found in the general logs. For example in my case I didn't have 'web' dyno but had 'clock'

```
2018-08-06T12:15:27+00:00 app[heroku-redis]: source=REDIS addon=redis-animated-99682 blablabla
2018-08-06T12:16:09.303680+00:00 app[clock.1]: Start request in 06.08.2018 12:08:09
```

, so

```
heroku logs -d clock
```

works fine for me

Comment: Which answer are you talking about?